# How to solve linear symbolic expressions in Sympy faster

Tags: python, math, sympy

last few days I have to manipulate and solve equations `expressions = 0` with respect to a variable lets say `x`, but with the characteristic `sy.diff(expressions,x)!=0` and `sy.diff(expressions,x,2) = 0`

Trying sy.solve(expression,x) takes for ever (haven't actually solved it, takes more that 10 hours on my kinda slow pc)

Is there a way around it?

Edit: an example of the actual expression

`r = sy.Symbol('r', real=True)`

`exp = -0.9*r*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*sqrt(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(rSS + 4.0*P(r))*(1.8*r*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - (1.8*r*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33) + (-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*(-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*u_φ(r)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*u_φ(r)**2 + 1.0*(r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - 1.0*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*sqrt(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(0.0795774715459477*r*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r)/((r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(3/2)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) + 0.0397887357729738*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r)/((r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(3/2)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)**2) + 0.0397887357729738*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(-2*r*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r) + 4*(r - 1)*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(2*(1 - r)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r) + 2*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) + 1.62*r - 1.62)*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r) + 2*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*B_θ(r)*Derivative(u_φ(r), r) + 2*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*u_φ(r)*Derivative(B_θ(r), r) + 2*(r*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81) + (1 - r)*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r))/((r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(3/2)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)**2))*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) - 1.0*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(-0.0716197243913529*r*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(7/2)*(2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r) + 0.0397887357729738*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(7/2)*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r) + 0.0397887357729738*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(7/2)*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*B_θ(r)*u_φ(r) + 0.0795774715459477*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**4*(-0.9*r*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - (0.9*r*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33) - (r**2 - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)**2*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*B_θ(r) + 0.0795774715459477*(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-r*B_θ(r) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*Derivative(B_θ(r), r))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)**2)*B_θ(r)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**4*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)**2*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))) + 0.5*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*sqrt(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(rSS + 4.0*P(r))*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*u_φ(r)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*u_φ(r)**2 + 1.0*(r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - 0.5*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*sqrt(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(rSS + 4.0*P(r))*(3.6*r*(0.9*r*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33) - (r**2 - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - (-3.6*r*(r**2 - 3.03701355989026e-33) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*u_φ(r)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*u_φ(r)**2 + 1.0*(r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) + (rSS + 1.0*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*P(r)*u_φ(r)**2/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-0.9*r*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(0.9*r*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33) - (r**2 - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2)/(-1.0*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*u_φ(r)**2/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + 1.0) - (rSS + 4.0*P(r))*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*u_φ(r)**2/(2*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*u_φ(r)**2 + 1.0*(r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) + (-0.9*r*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(0.9*r*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33) - (r**2 - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2)*P(r) + Derivative(P(r), r)`

with `P(r),u_f(r),Bth(r)` are functions of `r`

PS I think there is a command for putting the whole expression in a line with a Bar below

Comment: please provide more detailed information on the problem you are dealing with. what does  `expressions` look like? How do you set up your problem?

Comment: @mcsoini I put the expression.  Cant  put the process since it requires some other libraries that are kinda strange

Comment: @mcsoini sorry for long expressions :(

Comment: Which variable are you trying to solve for? You say x in the question but there is no x in the expression.

Comment: Your expression has things like `(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)` which is extremely ill-conditions if you are trying to solve for `r`.

Comment: @Oscar Benjamin  I'm trying to solve for r. Just used x as a more common symbols. So there is no way around it? Maybe I should use .replace() to substitute with zero those small numbers?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin  I have replaced the small values with 0, now I'm waiting for the solver to act.it works for an hour right now.

Comment: How can you solve for `r` if there are unknown functions like `P(r)`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I solve for `rSS`. The only variable i got is `r`. Wow, and I substitute afterwards `P(r)` etc.  Basically I run the command `sy.solve(exp,rSS)` and doesnt end.